# Difference between items in column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have store data where the open and close times are on different rows. The data is organized like this:

```
id   type   mon       tues       wed       ...
1    OPEN   09:30:00  09:30:00   10:00:00
1    CLOSE  22:00:00  22:00:00   21:00:00
2    OPEN   09:00:00  09:00:00   09:00:00 
2    CLOSE  22:00:00  22:00:00   21:00:00
```

The data is organized so that the open and close times (in local time) are on different rows.

I am trying to create a select query that would output data like this:

```
id   mon       tues       wed ...
1    12.5      12.5       11 
2    13        13         12
```

where the value of the output = `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CLOSE_time, OPEN_time))/3600.0`. In other words, the number of hours the store is open. The fact that the open and close times are on different rows is really throwing me off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by Self JOIN

```
select * from store s1 join store 
 s2 on s1.storeId = s2.storeId ;
```

So after self join the result set look like

```
id   s1.type   s1.type      s1.mon   s2.mon          s1.tues    s2.tues         
 1    OPEN     CLOSE       09:30:00   09:30:00        09:30:00  10:00:00
```

As you can see after the self join the open and close row in same same row , So you can apply your function to calculate the time

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `timestampdiff()`:

```
select id,
       timestampdiff(minute, topen.mon, tclose.mon) / 60 as mon,
       timestampdiff(minute, topen.tue, tclose.tue) / 60 as tue,
       . . .
from t topen join
     t tclose
     on topen.id = tclose.id and topen.type = 'OPEN' and tclose.type = 'CLOSE';
```

Comment: I get null values for the output of timestampdiff() when I use this query.